# What is node package walker?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, mongoose

I've taken up the job from another freelancer who isn't currently engaged on this project.

He has done some work which I don't understand. Can anyone help me with that.

Every time a user hires a parking spot, I want to notify a merchant.

here is the query to create a booking:

```
exports.createBooking = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await Auth.findOne({ _id: req.data.id });
    if (!user) return res.status(404).json({ error: "User not found" });

    const bookingDetails = new Booking({
      userId: req.data.id,
      parkingId: req.body.parkingId,
      duration: req.body.duration,
      date: moment(req.body.date).format("MMM DD, YYYY"),
      startTime: req.body.startTime,
      endTime: req.body.endTime,
      paymentAmount: req.body.paymentAmount,
      isFeePaid: req.body.isFeePaid,
      status: "sent",
    });

    bookingDetails.populate("walkerId");
    const save = await bookingDetails.save();
    // send notification to walker

    let notification_data = {
      name: `${owner.basicInfo.fullName}`,
      date: moment(req.body.date).format("MMM DD, YYYY"),
      startTime: req.body.startTime,
    };

    let { title, body } = notificationTypes.addBooking(notification_data);

    let data = {
      senderId: req.data.id,
      receiverId: req.body.walkerId,
      notificationSendTo: "walker",
      title,
      body,
    };

    sendNotification(data);

    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      msg: "Service Booked",
      data: { details: save },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
};
```

And the booking schema looks like this:

```
const bookingSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    parkingId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Parking",
    },
    userId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Auth",
    },
    duration: {
      type: String,
    },
    date: {
      type: String,
    },
    startTime: {
      type: Date,
    },
    endTime: {
      type: Date,
    },
    isFeePaid: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },

    status: {
      type: String,
      enum: [
        "confirmed",
        "sent",
        "pending",
        "accepted",
        "rejected",
        "cancelled",
        "start",
        "completed",
      ],
    },

    isBookingCancelled: {
      cancelBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
      },
      value: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
      cancellationReason: {
        type: String,
        maxlength: 255,
        trim: true,
      },
    },
    paidAmount: {
      type: Number,
    },
    paymentId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Payment",
    },
    paymentAmount: {
      type: Number,
    },
    isStarted: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    isEnabled: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

I am aware that the schema lacks a walkerId, which would cause an error to be thrown, but I have never used walker thus I have no idea how to incorporate it.

Comment: `walker` implements a _"nodejs directory walker"_.

Comment: @robertklep Sorry, but what is that? I have never heard this before.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/walker

Comment: @robertklep What it is doing in my code if it's a directory walker. Because I took over this code from a different freelancer who isn't working on it right now, could you kindly clarify what this is?

Comment: I don't see your code using the `walker` module anywhere. I do however see a string with the word `"walker"` and an object with a `walkerId` property. If I was reading this code I'd assume that a `walker` is a person who walks. Perhaps referring to parking jockeys/valets who walk to the car and park the car for the customer. Presumably this sends the notification to the person (human) whose job is to be the "walker" in the system